# Chartjs: update the min and maximum of the yaxes ticks on a click

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using chartjs to draw a line chart. I am making these charts dynamically and there can be 2 to 10 charts depending on the different data types. Right now i want to update the chart when i click a button or a text. This update will change the `min` and `max` of the `y-axes ticks`. I have try to do it in the javascript console on one chart by doing this

`myChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min=some_value;`

`myChart.update();`

but the problem is how would i change it when i click on a text or button. Is i have to make a legend?

this is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdqkLtc2/2/) for a test run.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

- Add the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/)
- Add a button, I added `<button id="action">action</button>`
- Add a jQuery trigger that executes the 2 lines on click:

`$('#action').off().on('click', function() {
  myLineChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = -50;
  myLineChart.update();
})`

See: https://jsfiddle.net/gdqkLtc2/3/

Comment: actually i was thinking about having something in the chart so it could automatically update that particular chart instance. As i have said in my question that there could be 2 to 10 charts.

Comment: I have tried your solution one problem i am getting is how revert back i mean i want to actually toggle the between min and then the default one.

Comment: @fatpotato To toggle the values you need to have an extra variable that will hold the possible values and another one to indicate the index to show. Take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/gdqkLtc2/4/.

About your first question related to adding 2 to 10 charts. I am not very sure what kind of framework are you using but why not simply copy-pasting the current HTML, and then populating each chart? I recommend to build the interface with the 10 charts and then only show the needed ones.

Comment: yeah i have figured that out by applying an unique attribute on every button which gives the information of the chart clicked.